# Python Pandas: Conditionally delete rows

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

[image]

Hi,
I want to delete rows whose values in columns col1 and col2 are both 0.

Right now, I have:

```
df = df[df['col1'] != 0 and df['col2'] != 0]
```

But I get an error message:
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

can anyone please explain how to implement this plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

You need bitwise `&` and add brackets for priority operators:

```
df = df[(df['col1'] != 0) & (df['col2'] != 0)]
```

Or:

```
df = df.query("'col1' != 0 & 'col2' != 0")
```

Comment: @JunJang - Glad can help!